Will using the 10A port on meter to test transformer cause it to pop?
I was testing the transformer in my furnace across the COM and 120V terminals when it popped, sparked, and left a burn mark on the COM terminal. Could it be because this nucklehead had the positive lead on the 10A port?

Maybe a year ago I was looking for DC current drains in a car with the 10 A socket and the range on DC current--no problem. Turned off the meter and set it aside for a while without changing the lead to the V-Ohm socket. Then of course picked it up, turned the function switch to DC Volts and touched it across the 12 V battery.  Spark and blown fuse costing $20+.

Jim, that's exactly what I did - forgot to switch it over. It cost me a furnace transformer and I noticed a nick on one of my probes which I will replace. Thanks for your comment. It makes me feel more human than stupid.

The resistance of a typical meter on the 10A scale is less than 0.1 ohms. This is effectively a short. When you attached the meter leads across the COM and 120V terminals, you shorted the mains voltage which is why you got a spark and a burn mark. You are lucky nothing worse happened. You probably also blew the fuse in the meter (if it has one, not all meters fuse their high current ranges). I don't know the potential knucklehead but this type of thing is all too common when the operator is not aware of what he is doing or is careless.

Thank you for delving into cause and effect- I am a perfect example of what can happen when one is not paying attention and I should NEVER have had my probe plugged into the 10A port. And of course you're correct that I am lucky something worse didn't happen. I knew that immediately afterwards. Thanks so much for your reply!
